# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize AND jsonfreeze

Tags: c#, php, json, vb.net

I have a two simple PHP class

```
class Order{
    public $orderNo;
    public $lines = array();
    public $paid = false;

    public function addLine(OrderLine $line) {
        $this->lines[] = $line;
    }

public function setPaid($paid = true) {
        $this->paid = true;
    }
}

class OrderLine{

public function __construct($item, $amount){
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->amount = $amount;
}

    public $item;
    public $amount;
    public $options;
}
```

Serialize object uses https://github.com/mindplay-dk/jsonfreeze

...

```
$json = new JsonSerializer;
$data = $json->serialize($order);
```

Have output:

```
{
  "#type": "Order",
  "orderNo": 123,
  "lines": [{
    "#type": "OrderLine",
    "item": "milk \"fuzz\"",
    "amount": 3,
    "options": null
  },{
    "#type": "OrderLine",
    "item": "cookies",
    "amount": 7,
    "options": {
      "#type": "#hash",
      "flavor": "chocolate",
      "weight": "1\/2 lb"
    }
  }],
  "paid": true
}
```

Send the string XMLRPC in VB.NET

As using Newtonsoft JSON get a live object?

As well as how to create a compatible format by analogy with the json string of living VB.net OR C# object?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could start with. You create some classes with properties which represent the JSON Format (untested code, just as idea):

```
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("#type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("#orderNo")]
    public int OrderNo { get; set; 

    [JsonProperty("paid")]
    public bool Paid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lines")]
    public List<MyDataLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataLines
{
    [JsonProperty("#type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("options")]
    public MyDataLinesOptions Options { get; set; }

    // ... more
}

public class MyDataLinesOptions
{
    // ... more
}
```

Then you can serialize and deserialize the the data like this:

```
string json = "the json data you received";
MyData myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);

// ...

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
```

Comment: `<JsonProperty("#type")> _` thanks, it works, I realized the essence!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow completely ignored that it's vb.net, but I'm glad that it helps you to get the actual idea. Feel free to [upvote and accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped you and welcome to StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: stackoverflow great service!
for several years found a lot of issues and solutions.
the difficulty is the fact that I am not a Pro in English.
I had to use a translator to solve a very important question.
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"#type": "Order"

and

"#type": "OrderLine",

this is not a property, this is an indication of the type of the object